# How do I close this Gtk::MessageDialog before it's parent window is destructed?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, gtkmm4

I'm currently trying to create a simple Gtkmm program that has a button which spawns a dialog box. I'm currently having issues, however, as the destructor for the AppWindow class causes a segfault closing the dialog box. I check if the `unique_ptr` is `nullptr` before calling close, but even with that check it will crash if the dialog has already been closed before the main window has. Am I taking the correct approach here? Is the `unique_ptr` getting freed before the destructor is called?

*main.c*

```
#include "AppWindow.hpp"

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <gtkmm/application.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::shared_ptr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create("org.dylanweber.test");

    return app->make_window_and_run<AppWindow>(argc, argv);
}
```

*AppWindow.hpp*

```
#include <gtkmm/button.h>
#include <gtkmm/messagedialog.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma once

class AppWindow : public Gtk::Window {
  public:
    AppWindow();
    virtual ~AppWindow();

  private:
    Gtk::Button m_button;
    std::unique_ptr<Gtk::MessageDialog> dialog;

    void on_button_clicked();
};
```

*AppWindow.cpp*

```
#include "AppWindow.hpp"

AppWindow::AppWindow() : m_button("Hello, world!") {
    this->m_button.set_margin(10);
    this->m_button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &AppWindow::on_button_clicked));
    this->set_child(this->m_button);
}

AppWindow::~AppWindow() {
    if (this->dialog != nullptr) {
        this->dialog->close(); // seg fault here
    }
}

void AppWindow::on_button_clicked() {
    this->dialog = std::make_unique<Gtk::MessageDialog>(
        "Button clicked", false, Gtk::MessageType::QUESTION, Gtk::ButtonsType::OK);
    this->dialog->set_transient_for(*this);
    this->dialog->set_secondary_text("Hello");
    this->dialog->set_default_response(Gtk::ResponseType::OK);
    this->dialog->show();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just leaving the destructor function empty (e.g. AppWindow::~AppWindow() {})?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion in the comments is right, you should leave your destructor empty and not call `dialog->close()` there. To see why, note that this function is a wrapper for GTK C API function `gtk_window_close`, defined like this for `Gtk::Window class` (from which `Gtk::MessageDialog` inherits through `Gtk::Dialog`):

```
// in gtk/gtkmm/window.cc
void Window::close()
{
  gtk_window_close(gobj());
}
```

Here `gobj()` returns internal `gobject_` pointer (defined in `ObjectBase` class) pointing to C API's GTK handle, which current class incapsulates. This pointer is used inside `gtk_window_close` this way:

```
// in gtk/gtkwindow.c

void
gtk_window_close (GtkWindow *window)
{
  GtkWindowPrivate *priv = gtk_window_get_instance_private (window);

  if (!_gtk_widget_get_realized (GTK_WIDGET (window)))
    return;

  if (priv->in_emit_close_request)
    return;

  g_object_ref (window);

  if (!gtk_window_emit_close_request (window))
    gtk_window_destroy (window);

  g_object_unref (window);
}

// in gtk/gtkwidgetprivate.h

static inline gboolean
_gtk_widget_get_realized (GtkWidget *widget)
{
  return widget->priv->realized;
}
```

As VS debugger told when running your example, segfault happens because `widget` is 0 in `_gtk_widget_get_realized`. It was cleared when dialog was closed, because by default closing (through `close` method or close button) a window means destroying it, as you can see e.g. by a call to `gtk_window_destroy` inside `gtk_window_close`. This destroy using GTK's C API `gtk_window_destroy` function through a pretty complex callback mechanism reaches appropriately registered C++ functions relating to memory management. Data breakpoint helped pinpoint exactly where `gobject_` was set to 0 - `Object::destroy_notify_` (which itself was indirectly called from reference counting code of GTK because dialog's reference count dropped to 0):

```
// gtk/gtkmm/object.cc
void Object::destroy_notify_()
{
  //Overriden.
  //GTKMM_LIFECYCLE

  #ifdef GLIBMM_DEBUG_REFCOUNTING
  g_warning("Gtk::Object::destroy_notify_: this=%p, gobject_=%p\n", (void*)(Glib::ObjectBase*)this, (void*)gobject_);
  if(gobject_)
    g_warning("  gtypename=%s\n", G_OBJECT_TYPE_NAME(gobject_));
  #endif

  //Actually this function is called when the GObject is finalized, not when it's
  //disposed. Clear the pointer to the GObject, because otherwise it would
  //become a dangling pointer, pointing to a non-existent object.
  gobject_ = nullptr;

  if(!cpp_destruction_in_progress_) //This function might have been called as a side-effect of destroy_() when it called g_object_run_dispose().
  {
    if (!referenced_) //If it's manage()ed.
    {
      #ifdef GLIBMM_DEBUG_REFCOUNTING
      g_warning("Gtk::Object::destroy_notify_: before delete this.\n");
      #endif
      delete this; //Free the C++ instance.
    }
    else  //It's not managed, but the C gobject_ just died before the C++ instance..
    {
      #ifdef GLIBMM_DEBUG_REFCOUNTING
      g_warning("Gtk::Object::destroy_notify_: setting gobject_ to 0\n");
      #endif
    }
  }
}
```

So, after closing a dialog, `MessageDialog`'s internal handle is cleared to 0 (BTW, MessageDialog destructor is not called during this, which I also checked in a debugger), and since you call a `close` function which assumes it isn't, you get memory access problems. Destructor correctly works in case `gobject_` was already cleared, so you don't get problems with recreating `MessageDialog` in `on_button_clicked` after it was closed (where `std::unique_ptr` calls destructor for previous object if it's present), as well as in case `gobject_` still points to valid object, so you shouldn't have problems with it even if dialog wasn't closed before recreation. For the same reasons, `MessageDialog` destructor called in `AppWindow` destructor is OK regardless of whether the dialog was closed before the window.

P.S. Note that the gtkmm `.cc` files here are from vcpkg buildtrees, generated using gtkmm's custom preprocessing `gmmproc` tool during build process from `.ccg` source files, so you won't find them in repositories.

Comment: So, in your recommendation, you suggest just letting the `unique_ptr` destructor get automatically called and that will guarantee it will be safely closed & destroyed when the window is destroyed because it is the window's class member... sounds good enough for me.

Comment: @dylanweber Yes, exactly. `unique_ptr` destructor will call `MessageDialog` destructor which will do cleanup correctly without assuming that internal `gobject_` is still valid, which `close`/`gtk_window_close` for some reason does assume.